# Showing that the supremum norm and the $L^1$ norm are not equivalent

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I've been trying to prove that in $C[a,b]$ there is no C such that $Cd_{\infty}(f,g))\leq d_{1}(f,g)$ with $d_{\infty}(f,g)=\sup {|f(x)-g(x)|}$ and $d_{1}(f,g)=\int_{a}^{b} |f(x)-g(x)|dx$. And well, proving that and proving $i_{1,\infty}:(C[a,b],d_{1}) \rightarrow (C[a,b],d_{\infty})$ is not continuous is the same so I proved that for the $C[0,1]$ interval which is pretty easiest to prove, but I haven't been able to prove it in $C[a,b]$ for any $a,b\in \mathbb{R} $, could you guys help me out?

EDIT: I will be more specific, I want to prove that for $i_{1,\infty}:(C[a,b],d_{1}) \rightarrow (C[a,b],d_{\infty})$ no matter what $\delta$ I choose, if I fix $\varepsilon=1/2$, $B_{1}(f_{1},\delta) \not\subset B_{\infty}(f_{1},1/2)$ with $f_{1}$ some 'usefull' function in $C[a,b]$

Thanks so much.

Comment: What is your proof for $[0,1]$? And why can't you adapt it to $[a,b]$?

Comment: $i_{1,\infty}:(C[a,b],d_{1}) \rightarrow (C[a,b],d_{\infty})$, so $ i_{1,\infty}(f(k))=f(k)$, then I pick some function$ f_{1}=k^{n}$ and $f_{2}=0$, then $d_{1}$ tends to 0 in [0,1] and $d_{\infty}$ tends to 1 in [0,1] :c

Comment: If you set $C=0$ then it is true.

Comment: I need a ball's continuity argument cause we are not allowed to use convergence. :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $n\in \Bbb N$ let $f_n$ be linear on $[0,1/2n]$ and on $[1/n,1]$ with $f(0)=f(1/n)=0$ and $f(1/2n)=1.$ Let $f(x)=0$ for $x\in [1/n,1].$

For $n\in N$ we have $d_1(f_n,0)=1/2n$ and $d_{\infty}(f_n,0)=1.$

So there is no $positive$ $ C  $ such that $Cd_{\infty}(f_n,0)\leq d_1(f_n,0)$ for all $n\in \Bbb N.$

The $d_{\infty}$ open ball $B_{\infty}(0,1)$ of radius $1,$ centered at the function $0,$ contains no member of $\{f_n:n\in \Bbb N\}.$  So there is no $r>0$ such that the $d_1$ open ball $B_1(0,r)$ is a subset of $B_{\infty}(0,1)$ because $B_1(0,r)\supset \{f_n: 2n>1/r\}\ne \emptyset. $

Comment: $d_1(f,g)$ is the average distance from $f(x)$ to $g(x)$ while  $d_{\infty}(f,g)$ is the largest distance from $f(x$) to $g(x).$ Intuitively, since the domain $[0,1]$ is an infinite set, we should not expect $d_{\infty}\leq (1/C) d_1$ for all $f,g,$ even for continuous $f,g.$

Comment: Thanks so much sir! Super clear! :)